# Create a dictionary from a list of key and multi list of values in Python

Tags: python, hash-map

I have a list of key:

```
list_date = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU","FRI"]
```

I have many lists of values that created by codes below:

```
list_value = list()
for i in list(range(5, 70, 14)):
    list_value.append(list(range(i, i+10, 3)))
```

Rules created that:

- first number is 5, a list contains 4 items has value equal x = x + 3, and so on [5, 8, 11, 14]
- the first number of the second list equal: x = 5 + 14, and value inside still as above x = x +3

  [[5, 8, 11, 14], [19, 22, 25, 28], [33, 36, 39, 42], [47, 50, 53, 56], [61, 64, 67, 70]]

I expect to obtain a dict like this:

```
collections = {"MON":[5, 8, 11, 14], "TUE" :[19, 22, 25, 28], "WED":[33, 36, 39, 42], "THU":[47, 50, 53, 56], "FRI":[61, 64, 67, 70]}
```

Then, I used:

```
zip_iterator = zip(list_date, list_value)
collections = dict(zip_iterator)
```

To get my expected result.

I tried another way, like using the `lambda` function.

```
for i in list(range(5, 70, 14)):
    list_value.append(list(range(i,i+10,3)))
    couple_start_end[lambda x: x in list_date] = list(range(i, i + 10, 3))
```

And the output is:

```
{<function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F0711F0>: [5, 8, 11, 14], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F071310>: [19, 22, 25, 28], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F071280>: [33, 36, 39, 42], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F0710D0>: [47, 50, 53, 56], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F0890D0>: [61, 64, 67, 70]}
```

I want to ask there is any better solution to create lists of values with the rules above? and create the dictionary `collections` without using the `zip` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative approach is to take advantage of `enumerate()` -- which allows
you to iterate over what could be thought of as a `zip()` of a list's indexes and
values. To my eye, this version seems a bit clearer and simpler.

```
days = ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI']

d = {
    day : [
        (5 + i * 14) + (j * 3)
        for j in range(4)
    ]
    for i, day in enumerate(days)
}

print(d)
```

Comment: Personally, I always use ```itertools.product``` whenever there is a cartesian product involved: ```d = {day: (5 + i * 14) + (j * 3) for i,(j,day) in it.product(range(4), enumerate(days))}```.

Comment: Just noticed the answers do not match. I retract my statement.

Comment: @Kevin: excuse me! but what is "it" in "it.product()"

Comment: @Scorpisces `import itertools as it`. But `product()` doesn't really help here.

Comment: One reason it's simpler/clearer is that it doesn't need the OP's limit `70`, as it simply goes as far as the days. And `range(4)` is also a lot clearer for the intention "4 items" than the limit `i+10`.

Comment: Overall agree, though you could drop the parens in `(5 + i * 14) + (j * 3)`; `5 + 14*i + 3*j` is clear enough

Comment: Also you needn't write `3*j` at all - you can instead move that to `j in range(0, 12, 3)` to avoid the multiplication.

Comment: @Reinderien Both of your suggestions are reasonable enough. I don't have a strong opinion one way or another, but I do suspect that readability is helped a small increment by keeping the not-required parens, keeping the looping mechanism simpler, and consolidating all math in a single location. But that's just a hunch.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that, as FMc's, has the advantage of not having to calculate/specify range limits (your `70` and `i+10`):

```
from itertools import count, islice

days = ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI']

d = {day: list(islice(count(start, 3), 4))
     for day, start in zip(days, count(5, 14))}

print(d)
```